# Is it possible to migrate an Adobe Fonts / Typekit account's fonts from one team member to another?

Tags: untagged

We have a team license for Adobe Creative Cloud. One part of this is [Adobe Fonts](https://fonts.adobe.com/) (previously called Typekit), a font licensing and hosting platform. A team member can add fonts to a project, and when we make a website they will be hosted for free as part of our plan.

We have a team member leaving and need to cancel their account, however all the websites we currently have using their account will (I assume) lose access to their fonts.

Is there a way to migrate an Adobe fonts account from one team member to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had this problem after being freelance for years, but then hired on as staff. I didn't want to lose all the fonts I had gathered over the years though! SO here's my workaround solution:
I went into **illustrator** in my old, personal account, hit **T for the type tool**, and lorem ipsum came up. Then, if you **toggle the arrow next to the font**, there is an option to filter in the top left. **Click on the icon that's a little cloud with a checkmark**, and it will show only your adobe activated fonts. I then copy pasted my lorem ipsum and changed each one methodically to each font in my Adobe font library. Not fun, but it only took me about 15 minutes so not too bad. I then saved this illustrator document locally, called it "typemigration.ai" or something like it. Then I signed out of my old Adobe cc account and signed into my new one, opened the file, and it prompted me with the missing fonts window. I simply selected activate, and boom. all my fonts are now active on my new account.
Not the easiest solution per se, but I thought it was a good enough workaround to share and I hope it helps! :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [Adobe site](https://www.adobe.com/products/pricing-info/cct-pricing-info.html):

> **What do I get with Creative Cloud for teams that I don’t get with an individual subscription?**
> Creative Cloud for teams includes
> everything in Creative Cloud plus a web-based Admin Console for easy
> license management with the **ability to reassign licenses**, centralized
> IT deployment tools, advanced 24/7 technical support, 1:1 sessions
> with Adobe product experts, and more.
>
> **Do the list prices for Creative Cloud for teams cover one user or my entire team?**
> **Prices shown are per user** and reflect the monthly price
> per team member if you choose to pay each month or the annual price
> per team member if you choose to pay up front.
>
> **Can I use my Creative Cloud software on more than one computer?**
> Yes. While you can’t use the apps on different computers at the same
> time, **you can install the apps on more than one computer** and activate
> (sign in) on up to two computers.

**So yes, you can.**

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote. Is the answer incorrect? Is Adobe lying about it? I would expect you would accept the answer instead. Am I probably missing something?